# Display Multiple Images from Json in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, image, axios

I've managed to create a mockup json that i need to test a json request via axios on a react app.

For now, i can console.log the json file structure and can assign the data for the link.

The problem is that my content it's not being rendered correctly in the DOM via Map Method. the images are not appearing.

````
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class DesignItem extends Component {
  state = { 
    isLoading: true,
    designs: [],
    error: null
   }

   componentDidMount () {
     axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dadd81c2d0000e0f5e4bd57')
     .then (res => {
       console.log(res.data);
       const designs = res.data;
       this.setState({designs})
     })
   }
  render() { 
    return ( 
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.state.designs.map(designs => (
// this one is appearing right as expected
        <Link to={designs.productPage}>
        <div className="design-item" key={designs.id}>
// this image doesn't appear. the URL is there but the image it's broken
          <img src={designs.featUrl} alt="" />

        </div></Link>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment> 
    );
  }
}

export default DesignItem;```
````

Comment: have you tried inspecting the <img> element in your browser? What is the "src" showing?

Answer (score 1):

```
<React.Fragment>
  {this.state.designs.map(designs => (
    <Link to={designs.productPage} key={designs.id}> // I think the key must be put here instead on the div
        <div className="design-item">
          <img src={designs.featUrl} alt="" />
        </div>
   </Link>
  ))}
</React.Fragment>
```

Also upon checking the data, the image source was like this:

```
../images/products/alexandre-iii/0.jpg
```

Maybe that is why it is not showing up, if you could change the url to something like:

```
https://your-domain.com/public/images/products/alexandre-iii/0.jpg
```

It will show up.